# Loading LLVM passes on Cygwin

Tags: dll, cygwin, llvm

I am trying to write an LLVM pass on Windows using Cygwin. When I make the project, a dll gets created in the Release/bin directory instead of a .so file in the Release/lib directory. The latter is what is shown in the LLVM document. When I try to load this dll using the -load flag, nothing happens.

```
$opt -load ../../../Release/bin/Pass.dll -help
```

The pass that I am trying to load isn't printed after this. How do I get this right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no dynamic linking on windows (this is OS weirdness), so you cannot use the plugins at all, unfortunately.

Well, in fact you can somehow, but for this you'd need to link the whole LLVM into big .dll, link opt with such a library and only then there is a possibility that stuff might work.